# StringBuffer equal to string but not working

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I'm trying to check the with an if-statement if two strings are the same(which they are), but it doesn't work. Here is my code and my first input value  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEkr7.jpg) . In the image at the bottom you see the first string value(   "Ticket is valid")

```
int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("\"Ticket is valid\"");
                if(sb.toString().equals(sb1.toString())){
                    textView.setText("SCANNED: "+sb1.toString());
                }

                return sb.toString();

            }
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no spaces around the string you read from the connection? Because in that case you need to convert it to string and `trim()` it first.

Comment: From the look of the `Toast` message I think there are extra spaces in the beginning of the first string. `trim()` both string to remove those extra spaces then compare them.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `.trim()` to the `sb.toString()`